# Creating an instance of an object within an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, instance

I am trying to create a new instance (of an `Expander`) and put it inside a `StackPanel` every time one variable is not equal to another.

The problem; however, seems to be that I can't access the variable outside the if function.
I get:

> "Error The name 'expand' does not exist in the current context"

If I declare the new instance outside the function then the application works as expected running once through the if statement. The second time it runs through the if statement I get an error:

> "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget."

```
 if (lastStatement != first.ToString())   {

     i++;
     Expander expand = new Expander();

     expand.Name = "expander" + i.ToString();   

     stackpanel1.Children.Add(expand); //This where the error is
 } expand.Content += ones; // I need to place this here for the code to work
```

This is the case where I get:

> "Error The name 'expand' does not exist in the current context"

The second attempt (when I have create the instance outside the statement) I get:

> "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring the variable and creating a new instance can be done in separate steps.  You can simply declaring it outside of your `if`-block and instantiate it inside, however, you will still need to set it to a valid value before you try to use it or you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

Something like this:

```
Expander expand;

if (lastStatement != first.ToString())
{
    i++;
    expand = new Expander();
    expand.Name = "expander" + i.ToString();   
    stackpanel1.Children.Add(expand);
} 
else
{
    expand = ... // set expand to some other instance of expander
}

expand.Content += ones;
```

However, it looks like you're using some sort of loop. In which case you *might* be trying to to only create new `Expander`'s on certain conditions, but reuse the previous `Expander` otherwise. In that case you'd need to declare the variable outside the loop block as well.

Something like this:

```
Expander expand = null;

foreach(...)
{
    if (lastStatement != first.ToString())
    {
        i++;
        expand = new Expander();
        expand.Name = "expander" + i.ToString();
        stackpanel1.Children.Add(expand);
    } 

    expand.Content += ones;
}
```

Comment: Thanks PSWG, it worked. What I did was simply declare the expander to null outside the function and call it locally.